# Unable to set correct remote path to document root

Tags: mamp-pro

Using MAMP 5 Pro, on a Mac. Remote site is hosted on dreampress. The remote wordpress installation lives in sitename.studio (yes, it is in the .studio tld). When I log onto the site from a ftp client with the same credentials I enter in the remote tab im mamp pro, I see several folders, things like maildir, and also the "sitename.studio" folder. The wordpress files are definitely in there.

So, as far as I understand in the "Path" field it should simply be "sitename.studio" because that is the name of the folder.

However, I get an error 3010 "The path to your remote document root is incorrect". It has to be a relative path, but the field won't let me enter a forwardslash as the first character.

Might the program be getting confused by the dot studio ?